# Difference between ESX,KVM and QEMU

Tags: ubuntu, qemu, kvm, esx

What are the major differences between ESX, KVM and QEMU?

Answer (score 4):

Qemu is an open source  user-space virtual machine monitor. It uses binary translation to run the guest instructions.

```
Pros : 
1) Has support of helpers which help a lot in debugging
2) Can be used to run guest of a different ISA. (You can emulate an ARM guest on x86 desktop)
3) Does not need hardware support
4) code is available. you can modify it for debugging
```

Cons:

```
1) Slow
```

KVM is an open source virtual machine monitor which is implemented in the linux kernel. Qemu can run a guest on KVM using the /dev/kvm interface.

```
Pros:
1) very fast
2) code is available in the kernel tree. you can modify it for debugging

Cons:
1) needs hardware support
2) Requires a user level software for interfacing (generally qemu)
```

VMX is a virtual machine monitor by VMWare. The source code of VMX is not freely available. But it supports both user space as well as hardware supported emulation.

```
Pros : 
1) Very easy to use. GUI is good.
2) Fast and configurable. 

Cons :
1) Cannot modify it to obtain more information about the guest.
```

Comment: What about ESX? Is VMX is alias of ESX

Comment: Taken from http://blogs.vmware.com/vapp/2009/11/index.html.      For VMware products we use the form ‘vmx-X’ where X is VMware's virtual hardware version number. The import process will convert the virtual hardware to use this version number. Several hardware versions may be defined by using space as a delimiter e.g. “vmx-04 vmx-07”

Comment: btw, if your question is answered you must accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the information which you have provided, it is so helpful to me. The hypervisor concept is entirely new to me, so inorder to clarify my doubt i asked the above question i.e., is VMX and ESX are same. 

I am not denying your answer Prathmesh, the reply which you have given has helped me a lot in getting into the hypervisors concept.

Thank you.